# mocking private variables in a function for testing Junit4

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I am writing a Junit4 test for a function which has Boolean variables which are set based on other functions. How can I mock these Boolean variable in my test case.

The function I am testing

```
private var operatorSigned = false
private var engineerSigned = false


override fun onValidationSucceeded() {
    if (operatorSigned && engineerSigned) {
        sendQualityControlCheck()
    } else {
        view.showToastMessage(app.getString(R.string.quality_control_signatures_not_complete))
    }
}
```

This is how the values are set

```
override fun signatureSigned(name: String, svgSignature: String, bitmapSignature: Bitmap, signatureType: SignatureType) {
    val svgSignatureGzipped = CompressionTools.gzipCompress(svgSignature)
    when (signatureType) {
        SignatureType.OPERATOR -> {
            operatorSignature = QualityControlSignature(svgSignatureGzipped, DateTime())
            operatorSigned = true
            view.operatorSignatureSigned()
        }
        SignatureType.ENGINEER -> {
            engineerSignature = QualityControlSignature(svgSignatureGzipped, DateTime())
            engineerSigned = true
            engineerName = name
            view.engineerSignatureSigned()
        }
    }
}
```

My test case

```
@Test
fun `must show toast message when onValidationSucceeded is called and operatorSigned is false`() {
    `when`(app.getString(R.string.quality_control_signatures_not_complete)).thenReturn("Operator and Engineer signature required")
    presenter.onValidationSucceeded()
    verify(view).showToastMessage("Operator and Engineer signature required")
}
```

I want to be able to change values on operatorSigned and engineerSigned how can I do that.

Comment: How are they set? In the code you have posted they are always `false`. (i.e. if they are set in other functions, then call the other functions to set them).

Comment: but they are based on too many other parameters

Comment: updated my question

Comment: To me this seems like a class design problem. If you have you signature code as its own class and inject it in, it might be easier to test

Comment: Don't try to test "the code". Unittests verify the *public observable* **desired behavior** of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's pretend the `OPERATOR` path of your code sets these booleans to false:

```
@Test
fun `must show toast message when onValidationSucceeded is called and signature is Operator`() {
    // Given
    signatureSigned("unusedName", "unusedSig", null, SignatureType.OPERATOR) 
`when`(app.getString(R.string.quality_control_signatures_not_complete)).thenReturn("Operator and Engineer signature required")
    // When
    presenter.onValidationSucceeded()
    // Then
    verify(view).showToastMessage("Operator and Engineer signature required")
}
```

(had to pretend because right now the code you shared only ever sets the booleans to true).

You are now unit testing the classes *behaviour* not testing *how* that behaviour is coded. For example, now if those booleans where refactored out for an Int value. This test would still pass without you having to touch it, **that is a good thing**!

---

Or if your code stays as is. You can test like this:

```
@Test
fun `must show toast message when onValidationSucceeded is called and has not been signature signed`() {
    // Given
    // We haven't signature signed (see verify)
   `when`(app.getString(R.string.quality_control_signatures_not_complete)).thenReturn("Operator and Engineer signature required")
    // When
    presenter.onValidationSucceeded()
    // Then
    verify(view).showToastMessage("Operator and Engineer signature required")
    verify(view, never()).operatorSignatureSigned()
    verify(view, never()).engineerSignatureSigned()
}
```

---

How to mock a static method (hint you don't, you move it to the edge of your system and worry about it later).

Your class right now:

```
class MyClass {

    override fun signatureSigned(name: String, svgSignature: String, bitmapSignature: Bitmap, signatureType: SignatureType) {
        val svgSignatureGzipped = CompressionTools.gzipCompress(svgSignature)
        ...
    }

}
```

So you need to remove the static call, for another class that can do the static call as a dependency.

```
interface SignatureCompressor {
    fun compress(signature: String)
}

class GZipSignatureCompressor : SignatureCompressor {
    override fun compress(signature: String) {
        return CompressionTools.gzipCompress(signature)
    } 
}
```

Now your class becomes:

```
class MyClass(private val compressor: SignatureCompressor) {

    override fun signatureSigned(name: String, svgSignature: String, bitmapSignature: Bitmap, signatureType: SignatureType) {
        val svgSignatureGzipped = compressor.compress(svgSignature)
        ...
    }

}
```

and you can mock the compressor:

```
 val cut = MyClass(mockk())
```

**You also don't need the interface if you only have one implementation of compressing**

Comment: thank you that is a perfect Idea but one question, in signatureSigned function how can i mock val svgSignatureGzipped = CompressionTools.gzipCompress(svgSignature) it gives me an error that svgSignatureGzipped is null

Comment: Wrap the static method call into a Class `GZipCompressor` or something, then pass this as a dependency of the class.

Comment: did not understand how to do that sorry

Comment: I'll add it to the answer